# Incorrect path in form_for helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I can't figure out how to correctly write a url path in form_for for creating a new object. I tried to do it different ways, but no luck. I suppose there is some particular form of url's that can include objects' id's.
[image]

**views/tasks/new.html**

```
<%= form_for :task, url: [@task.user, @task] do |f| %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: params[:user_id] %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

**rake routes**

[image]

**controllers/tasks_controller.rb**

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authorize, only: [:edit, :new, :destroy]

  def index
    @tasks = Task.where(user_id: params[:user_id])
  end

  def show
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to users_path
  end

  def edit
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @task = Task.new
  end

  def create
    @task = Task.new(task_params)

    if @task.save
      redirect_to @task
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end


  def update
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])

    if @task.update(task_params)
      redirect_to @task
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @task.destroy
    respond_to {|format| format.js }
  end

  private

    def task_params
     params.require(:task).permit(:title, :description)
    end
 end
```

**views/tasks/index.html**

```
<p align="right"><%= link_to 'Users', users_path %> <%= link_to 'Tasks', user_tasks_path %></p>
<h3>Tasks database</h3>
<table>
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
<tr id="task_<%= task.id %>">
  <td>
    <b>Title:</b>
    <i> <%= task.title %></i>
  </td>

  <td>
    <b>Description: </b>
    <i><%= task.description %></i>
  </td>

  <td>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_task_path(task.user, id: task.id) %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= link_to 'Delete', user_task_path(task.user, id: task.id),
        data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :method => :delete, remote: true %>
  </td>
</tr>
<% end %>

<tr>
   <td><%= link_to 'Create task', new_user_task_path %></td>
   <td><%= link_to 'Back to Users', users_path %></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: try this: `<%= form_for [@task.user, @task] do |f| %>`

Comment: make it only `<%= form_for @task, url: new_user_task_path(@task.user) do |f| %>`

Comment: your user does not exist currently for '@task' because you have done @task = Task.new. is your user set in some instance variable on the new page of task.

Comment: @Deep Unfortunately nothing changed

Comment: Try this `<%= form_for [current_user, @task] do |f| %>`

Comment: @Pavan You're correct :)

Comment: @Deep You may get surprised, but even that option didn't work. Pavan nailed it.

Comment: As @Athar said your `@task.user` doesn't exist or else the first suggestion would have worked. And same for the next suggestion. And this not a test or competition we are here to help other which I was trying to do and also to learn from others as well. This is not the first time at many instances I have learned many things from @Pavan and many other members. Finally we are glad you got help and your code works now. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `nested_routes` for `tasks` and `users`, so changing your `form_for` like below should solve your problem

```
<%= form_for [current_user, @task] do |f| %>
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. But for some reason It can't be preserved for a particular user.  When I open user's list of tasks there are no those.

Comment: @AlexanderShmatko I didn't get you.

Comment: @AlexanderShmatko In the controller you have nowhere assigned the user to the task that is why, either you can add that in strong parameters or instead of `Task.new` you can use `current_user.tasks.build`

Comment: @Deep Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: @Deep But I'm interested anyway what exactly `.build` part do?

Comment: You can assume it just like `Task.new(user_id: current_user.id)`. The `build` is used to build associated objects.

Answer (score 1):

Please can you try this:

```
<%= form_for([current_user, @task]) do |f| %>

  <p>
     <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: params[:user_id] %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
```

Comment: Hope, you have `current_user` value `<%= form_for([parent_object, child_object]) do |f| %>`

Comment: Thanks for a useful information. And how is current_user value different from a certain user's id?

Comment: `current_user` is the `user` object

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the routes it seems that you need to allow either the admin/user to create tasks for any user. So for this first add a `before_action` in your controller:

```
before_action :find_user

def find_user
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
end
```

Then in you form do it like:

```
<%= form_for [@user, @task] do |f| %>
```

Then in the `create` action of your controller do it like:

```
 def create
    @task = @user.tasks.build(task_params)

    if @task.save
      redirect_to @task
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

The above can be used when you need to save tasks for many user  and if you need that only the `current_user` tasks should be saved you can go with the above answers.

Comment: Invaluable information for me. Sorry, but I've already accepted another answer. But your post isn't any less helpful)